# When to use exponent rule $\sqrt x^2$ and when to square both sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am solving equations to see if the equation is a function or not.  I would like to know when to use exponent rules and when to square both sides?  The equation is $$x= \sqrt {1 - y^2}$$ I want to use an exponent rule but am unsure because the y squared term is under the radical. The exponent rule I want to use is $$ \sqrt {a^2}= a^\frac 22$$ If I apply that rule to the equation I get $$x=1^\frac 22 -y^\frac22$$ Then I can solve for y $$y=1-x$$. Yes y is a function of x.

The above is wrong because $ \sqrt { x^2}$ =
$ \lvert x \rvert$.  The $x^2$ means there will be a negative and positive number equal distance away.

Upon further research I’d like to find out if this following method is acceptable for the same problem.   $$ x = \sqrt {1-y^2} $$  $$x=1- \lvert y \rvert$$

$$ \lvert y \rvert= -x + 1$$

Not sure if this correct and still wondering if the absolute value sign would stop this equation from being a function.

Comment: It is not true that $\sqrt{a^2}=a^{\frac22}=a^1=a$. You can see this by trying $a=-1$.

Comment: (And even if it was true, it would not be true that $\sqrt{1-y^2}=1^{\frac22}-y^{\frac22}$.)

Comment: Is it true that when the $ \sqrt {}$ symbol is used it refers to the principle root which is the positive root?  That is why the fractional exponent rule only works for non negatives?

Comment: The fractional expononet rule is $ \sqrt {a^2}$ = $ a^ \frac 22$ = $a^1$ = a. This rule only works for the positive square root?

Comment: @Benp404: Yes, the notation $\sqrt{x}$ refers to the nonnegative square root of $x$. Hence, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is not equal to $x$ if $x$ is negative. For much the same reason, $\left(x^2\right)^{1/2}$ is not always equal to $x^1=x$. Again $x^{1/2}$ means the nonnegative square root of $x$.

Comment: "still wondering if the absolute value sign would stop this equation from being a function"  Stops it dead in the tracks.  If $|y| = f(x)$ then $y = \pm f(x)$ and so for a single value of $x$ we can have two values of $y$.  BANG! You're dead!  Not a function.

Comment: By the way though......... $(m + n)^k \ne m^k + n^k$ so  $(1-y^2) \ne (1-y)^2$ and $(1-y)^{\frac 22} \ne (1^{\frac 22} - y^{\frac 22})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y = f(x)$ is a function then if you ever have an $(x_1, y_1)$  you can *not* have an $(x_1, y_2)$ unless $y_1 = y_2$.

so that should tell you that if you ever have $x = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ then as $y^2 = (-y)^2$ you will also have $x = \sqrt{1 - (-y)^2}$ so if you ever have $(x,y)$ you will *also* have $(x,-y)$ and if $y \ne 0$ then $y \ne -y$ so it can't be a function.

Example:  If $y= \frac 12$ then $x = \sqrt{1-\frac 1{2^3}} = \frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and you have both $(\frac{\sqrt 3}2, \frac 12)$ *and* $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2, -\frac 12)$.  So it can't be a function.

There not really any rule that $\sqrt{a^2} \underbrace{=}_{true} (a^2)^{\frac 12}\underbrace{=}_{!!!FALSE!!!!} a^{\frac 22} = a$.

The is a rule that $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ and $|a| = \begin{cases} a\\-a\end{cases}$.

So $x = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ does mean that $x^2 = 1-y^2$ but WE MUST PUT A PIN IN AND REMEMBER THAT $1-y^2 \ge 0$ and $x \ge 0$.

And so $y^2 = 1-x^2$  (and we MUST remember that $x\ge 0$)

And so it is true that $\sqrt{y^2}=\sqrt {1-x^2}$.

!!BUT!!!! $\sqrt{y^2} \ne y$.

$\sqrt {y^2} = |y| = \begin{cases}y\\-y\end{cases}$ so

$\begin{cases}y\\-y\end{cases} = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and

$y = \begin{cases} \sqrt{1-x^2}\\-\sqrt{1-x^2}\end{cases}$.

So not a function.

Comment: Thanks for the trig example.  It seems like such an easy problem until trying to solve for y.  It looks like it is not a function.

Comment: It appears this problem takes on a similar form of $f(x)= \lvert x \rvert$. But it is only a disguise.  I am still working on it.  I want to test the y and x for range and domain.   The y is not isolated so that is complicated still for me.  How can there be a range or a domain if it is not a function?  I am working through that type of thought but this is a big advancement!

Comment: What are the ordered pairs that overlap and make this relationship not a function?  That is what I need to answer.  Almost there.

Comment: "What are the ordered pairs that overlap"  Uh... $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2, \frac 12)$ and $(\frac {\sqrt 3}2, -\frac 12)$.  But *ANY* $(\frac {1-y^2}2, y)$ and $(\frac {1-y^2}2, -y)$ will do.